# Is this function a member of the rapidly decreasing function space?

Tags: analysis

I want to know if the function $\varPhi(x)=e^{-ax^2+icx}$ for positive $a$, and $c$, belongs to the space of rapidly decreasing functions $\mathscr{S}$. I know intuitively that functions in $\mathscr{S}$ vanishes 'faster' than any inverse power of $|x|$ as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$, and it seems true for $\varPhi$ above.

I am only familiar with the formal definition of the space of rapidly decreasing functions given by: a function $\varPhi(x)$ belongs to $\mathscr{S}$ if and only if, given any $p,q=0,1,2,...$, there is a constant $C_{pq}$ (depending on $p,q$ and $\varPhi$) such that
$$
|x^p\varPhi^{(q)}(x)| \leq C_{pq}, \hspace{20px} -\infty<x<\infty.
$$

Unfortunately I have never even seen an example of how this definition could be used to prove that a function is a member of $\mathscr{S}$, partly because I'm not really a mathematics major and have never formally taken a course on analysis (which I think is the subject matter in which this question belongs to).

If it is indeed true that $e^{-ax^2+icx} \in \mathscr{S}$, I would be delighted if someone could sketch a proof of it for me, using the definition above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your fonction belongs to $\mathscr{S}$.

**Hint.** Since you may easily prove by induction that
$$
\partial_x^{(n)}\left(e^{-ax^2+icx}\right)=P_n(x) \times e^{-ax^2+icx}
$$ where $ P_n(x)$ is a complex polynomial of degre $n$ and since we always have
$$
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\left(Q_p(x) \times e^{-ax^2+icx}\right)=0 \quad (a>0, c \in \mathbb{R}),
$$ where $ Q_p(x)$ is any complex polynomial of degre $p$.

Comment: Okay, I suppose that the proof also uses |a*b|=|a|*|b| for complex a and b?

Comment: Oh, I think I know now. Your limit above implies that for every $\epsilon$>0, it is true that there exists a $\delta>0$ such that: $|x^p * P_q(x)*e^{-ax^2+icx}|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x|<\frac{1}{\delta}$. So you just pick $C_{pq}$ according to that?

Comment: @Kurome This is just because it is a known fact that $|x^p|e^{-ax^2} \to 0$ for every fixed value of $p$. Do you know this fact? Thanks.

Comment: Only intuitively, that decreasing exponential functions decay faster than algebraic functions.

Comment: @Kurome Yes, exactly. This is what is used here.

Comment: Well, proofs are always welcome.